# Why clickhouse 'DESCRIBE TABLE' returns 4 or 5 columns

Tags: clickhouse

Clickhouse [DESCRIBE TABLE](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/misc/#describe-table) returns sometime five columns:

- `name`: String
- `type`: String
- `default_type`: String
- `default_expression`: String
- `comment_expression`: String

Sometimes there is not *comment_expression* so it returns just four columns.

What explain this difference and how can I know how many columns the describe will return before requesting?

Edit : 
With the version of clickhouse above 19 there is a 6th column `codec_expression`
but the query seems to be more predictable and return alway six columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes there is not comment_expression so it returns just four columns.

I'd strongly assume that is an indication of inconsistent upgrade of the clickhouse server. The *comment_expression* column was introduced in this commit https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/bdcdc15b1eb398bf715e05fb3652a21650bbab68/dbms/src/Interpreters/InterpreterDescribeQuery.cpp#L50 . The sample block determines the data structure and it's mandatory, thus there is not correct way to generate less columns.

Comment: I think you right there is a little difference between my dev and prod environment. Thanks